# My break statement doesn't seem to be working correctly, it still loops once after executing

Tags: java

Let me start off by saying that I am a relatively newer coder and have little to no experience, I'm sorry if my questions may be easy to some people. I need to write a program that uses a while loop that will ask the user a question and if they have a certain number or above it, they will get a certain response, if not, they are told to try it again. I think I've done most of it right but everytime I put in the correct number, it doesn't break immediately and loops back one time before stopping.

```
public class TaffyTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Starting the Taffy Timer...");
        System.out.print("Enter the temperature: "); 
        while (true)
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int temp = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The mixture isn't ready yet.");
            System.out.print("Enter the temperature: ");
            if (temp >= 270)
            {
                System.out.println("Your taffy is ready for the next step!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `break` in the loop or in the `if-else`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the order so it is more logical

```
    System.out.println("Starting the Taffy Timer...");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int temp = 0;
    while (temp < 270)
    {
        System.out.println("The mixture isn't ready yet.");
        System.out.print("Enter the temperature: ");
        temp = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Your taffy is ready for the next step!");
```

Do things in the order that makes more sense.  Make the `while` dependdant on your condition.  Things that are to be done after the condition is met should be done after the loop.

**Result**

```
Starting the Taffy Timer...
The mixture isn't ready yet.
Enter the temperature: 800
Your taffy is ready for the next step!
```

Comment: The executed code is 
"Starting the Taffy Timer...
Enter the temperature: 800
The mixture isn't ready yet.
Enter the temperature: Your taffy is ready for the next step!"
I want the code to only say "Your taffy is ready for the next step!" whenever the temperature is equal to or above 270, sorry if I didn't make this clearer earlier

Comment: @Ali-Core Please check that your code is the same as mine.  I have added my output as well.